# Estou criando um jogo, como implementar um menu de pausa?

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um jogo no Android studio usando a classe SurfaceView que é instanciada na MainActivity e uma thread que é instanciada no SurfaceView, o problema é quando eu ligo e desligo a tela ele volta pro estado inicial, ou seja ele não salva as posições/state, na real, queria saber como implementar um menu de pausa ...

**IMAGENS**

antes de apertar o botão desligar tela (dei um toque na tela pra o [circulo/passaro] pular)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

depois de apertar o botão ligar tela (o [circulo/passaro] volta para posição de queda)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Código fonte abaixo***

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Game game;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    game = new Game(this);
    container.addView(game);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    game.cancela();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    game.inicia();
    new Thread(game).start();
      }
   }
```

**Classe Game (GameView)**

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements Runnable,View.OnTouchListener{
private final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
private boolean isRunning = true;
private Player passaro;
private Bitmap background;
private Tela tela;


public Game(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    inicializaElementos();
}

private void inicializaElementos() {
    tela = new Tela(getContext());
    this.passaro = new Player();
    Bitmap back = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.background);
    this.background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(back,
            tela.getLargura(), tela.getAltura(), false);

}

public void update() {
    passaro.update();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) continue;
        //Neste loop vamos gerenciar os elementos do Jumper.
        //
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        update();
        //
        //Aqui vamos desenhar os elementos do jogo!
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        passaro.desenhaNo(canvas);
        //
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

public void cancela() {
    this.isRunning = false;
}

public void inicia() {
    this.isRunning = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    passaro.pula();
    return false;
     }
  }
```

**Classe Player(passaro)**

```
public class Player {
private static final Paint vermelho = Cores.getCorDoPassaro();
private int x;
private static final int RAIO = 50;
private int y, velY = 0;
private int gravity = 1;
//private float fric = 0.3f;
//private boolean jump = false;

public Player() {
    this.y = 0;
    this.x = 100;
}

public void pula() {
    this.velY = -30;
    cai();
}

public void update() {
    if (chao()) {
        this.y = 1080 - RAIO;
        this.velY = 0;//(int) (-this.velY*this.fric);
    } else {
        cai();
    }
}


private boolean chao() {
    if (this.y >= 1080 - RAIO) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void cai() {
    this.y += this.velY;
    this.velY += this.gravity;
}


public void desenhaNo(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RAIO, vermelho);
   }
}
```

**Classe Tela**

```
public class Tela {
private DisplayMetrics metrics;

public Tela(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
}

public int getAltura() {
    return metrics.heightPixels;
}

public int getLargura() {
    return metrics.widthPixels;
   }
}
```

**Classe Cores**

```
public class Cores {
public static Paint getCorDoPassaro() {
    Paint vermelho = new Paint();
    vermelho.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    return vermelho;
   }
}
```

Comment: Seja mais específico na sua pergunta, coloque o que já tem de código. Imagens do problema na tela, etc.

Comment: @hugocsl acabei de colocar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer um pause dentro do jogo uma forma simples seria criar uma variável qualquer e checar dentro do loop do seu jogo.

Ex:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        if(isPaused) continue; // Aqui checa de o jogo esta pausado ou não;
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) continue;
        //Neste loop vamos gerenciar os elementos do Jumper.
        //
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        update();
        //
        //Aqui vamos desenhar os elementos do jogo!
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        passaro.desenhaNo(canvas);
        //
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

Agora para pausar o jogo e sair dele e depois voltar você precisa salvar as informações dele antes. Você pode utilizar o `onSaveInstanceState` para salvar e depois dentro do `onCreate` você recarrega elas.

```
static final String Tag_intQualquer = "tint";
static final String Tag_stringQualquer = "tstring";

int intQualquer;
String stringQualquer;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    savedInstanceState.putInt(Tag_intQualquer, intQualquer);
    savedInstanceState.putString(Tag_stringQualquer, stringQualquer);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // verifica se existe algo salvo para ser recarregado
    if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
        carrega os dados do jogo anterior
        intQualquer = savedInstanceState.getInt(Tag_intQualquer);
        stringQualquer = savedInstanceState.getInt(Tag_stringQualquer);
        // com os dados carregados você gera um Player e manda para para a classe Game
    } 
    else 
    {
        // recomeçar o jogo do inicio           
    }
}
```

depois é só fazer algumas modificações no construtor da sua classe `Game` para que ele tenha como receber um objeto `Player`

```
public Game(Context context, Player old) 
{
    super(context);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    inicializaElementos(old);
}

private void inicializaElementos(Player old)
{
    tela = new Tela(getContext());
    if(old == null)
    {
        this.passaro = new Player();
    }
    else
    {
        this.passaro = old;
    }
    Bitmap back = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.background);
    this.background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(back,
            tela.getLargura(), tela.getAltura(), false);
}
```

Comment: Eu discordo quanto ao `if (isPaused) continue;`, pois acaba gastando processamento e bateria de maneira desnecessária

Comment: Eu concordo com você discordando, hahaha. Alguma solução simples melhor? @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual seria a mais Andróidica de todas, mas desconheço. Essa solução seria baseada em implementar uma função que redesenharia a tela, que não estaria em laço. De experiência precisando manipular "interfaces com ação em tempo real", tenho expetimentos em Python com TkInter e PyGame. No caso do TkInter (uma interface que foi feita para ser programado baseada em eventos), depois de desenhar o frame, eu agendava outro desenho de frame para um tempo rápido, acho que 60 FPS, daí ao desenhar novamente levava em consideração o tempo decorrido do começo do desenho do frame anterior...

Comment: ... até o começo do frame atual (intervalo entre dois ticks), fazendo as movimentações baseado nessa janela de tempo. No caso do PyGame, que já era mais voltado a "interface em tempo real", eu fazia um laço infinito dormindo em torno de 17ms antes de começar a próxima iteração; para fazer os movimentos, também levava em consideração a diferença entre dois ticks, não o tempo em que eu havia pedido para dormir.

Comment: Nesse esquema aí, eu particularmente faria algo assim: `while (running) { long tick = getTick(); getNextFrameUpdater().updateFrame(tick); sleep(4); }`. Eu poderia ter posto para ser `sleep(17)` para ficar com 60 FPS, mas aí qualquer flutuação entre o `sleep()` e a próxima ação faria o Android perder um frame, então prefiro ter uma garantia maior de que vou desenhar de maneira fluida. Nota para o `getNextFrameUpdater()`: ele leva em consideração o estado interno do programa (tipo a variável `isPaused` que você citou) e seleciona como vai atualizar a tela; se tiver em pause, não será o do jogo